# Connections between a submatrix and a partitioned matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, block-matrices, smith-normal-form

I am thinkng about some relations between  a symmetric matrix $A_{n \times n}$ and    another symmetric matrix $M_{(n+1) \times (n+1)} = \left[
  \begin{array}{c |c}
   A & \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\-1 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \\
   \hline
   \begin{matrix} 0& 0 & -1 & 1 \end{matrix} &
   0
  \end{array}
  \right]
  $.

What I have in mind about that are signature, nullity and smith normal form.

[Eigenvalues of block matrix related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730299/eigenvalues-of-block-matrix-related)

https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/78B/jresv78Bn1p3_A1b.pdf

I read these two references. But I couldn't figure out yet.
I would appreciate it if you could share any ideas or comments.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Cauchy interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem)?

Comment: I haven't seen it yet, but I'll study it. Thank you for your comment!